# Char to long using ASCII values

Tags: c

I have to store ASCII value of each character in a char array in a long variable using c.
Example:
Suppose

```
char * string = "ABCD"
```

so long variable should be

```
long = 65666768
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Nevermind, I get it, you want to convert `"ABCD"` to the ASCII number for each char and concatenate the ASCII numbers in a string. You can use a loop and index similar to `size_t idx = 0; while (*string) {sprintf (buf + idx, "%02d", *string); string++; idx += 2; } buf[idx] = 0;`

Comment: `char` is yet another integral type. You may apply bit shift (`<<`) to it. Though, signed values and bit shift... May be, it's worth to intermediately convert them to the unsigned counter parts.

Comment: What is the expected output for `"abcde"`?

Comment: If char is abcde the the value of long should be 6566676869

Comment: @MohitJain but the ASCII value for `a` (lowercase) is `97`.

Comment: @MohitJain if your ascii string increase, you can't hold it in `long` variable (if u refer) bez max 4 bytes.

Comment: Sorry let char array be ABCDE

Comment: @MohitJain as babon noticed, lowercase a is 97, and most importantly lowercase d is 100... How are we expected to deal with 3-digit numbers? Are you sure you aren't meant to build a number made of two _hexadecimal_ digits per character (which would fit perfectly)?

Comment: @MohitJain What result do you want from the string "de"? Would that be `long result = 100101;` ?

Comment: @MohitJain: I asked explicitly about lowercase to unravel a corner case... again, what should `"abcde"` (97, 98, 99, 100, 101) produce?

Comment: @MohitJain What result do you want from the string "A\tB"? Would that be long `result = 650966;` or perhaps `result = 65966;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments, you can write the ASCII character values to another buffer (call it something other than `long`) by looping over the characters in `string` and writing the 2-digit ASCII character value to the buffer while advancing your `string` pointer by one and your `index` by two each iteration, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSTR 64   /* maximum string length (don't skimp) */   

int main (void) {

    char *string = "ABCD",
        buf[MAXSTR];
    size_t idx = 0;

    printf ("str: %s\n", string);

    while (*string) {   /* loop over each char in string */
        sprintf (buf + idx, "%02d", *string);   /* write ascii val to buf */
        string++;       /* increment string */
        idx += 2;       /* increment index */
    }
    buf[idx] = 0;       /* nul-terminate buf*/

    printf ("buf: %s\n", buf);  /* output result */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtoasciistr
str: ABCD
buf: 65666768
```

There is more than one way to do this, but this is quite easy, relying on a standard library function to write the ASCII value to your new buffer. Let me know if you have further questions.

Additionally, you will need to handle cases for ASCII values `<= c` (2-digit values) and those above with 3-digits -- that is left for you to add with a conditional.

If you do want to convert to the `long` value at the end, simply add,

```
long = longval;
longval = strtol (buf, NULL, 0);
```

To convert the ASCII characters stored in `buf` to the long value `longval` (you can also utilize the `endptr` parameter to `strtol` for error checking the conversion along with `errno` -- see [strtol(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) if that is what you want to do.

**Including the conversion to `long`**

As mentioned above, to convert the result in `buf` to long, simply add a call to `strtol` (with proper validations), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXSTR 64   /* maximum string length (don't skimp) */   

int main (void) {

    char *string = "ABCD",
        buf[MAXSTR],
        *endptr;
    size_t idx = 0;
    long longval = 0;
    errno = 0;

    printf ("str: %s\n", string);

    while (*string) {   /* loop over each char in string */
        sprintf (buf + idx, "%02d", *string);   /* write ascii val to buf */
        string++;       /* increment string */
        idx += 2;       /* increment index */
    }
    buf[idx] = 0;       /* nul-terminate buf*/

    printf ("buf: %s\n", buf);  /* output result */

    longval = strtol (buf, &endptr, 0);

    if (buf == endptr && longval == 0) {
        fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
    }
    else if (errno) {
        fputs ("error: under/overflow occurred.\n", stderr);
    }
    else
        printf ("longval: %ld\n", longval);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtoasciistr
str: ABCD
buf: 65666768
longval: 65666768
```

**To Handle All Printable Character (including Upper/lower Case)**

Include  and replace the loop with the following:

```
while (*string) {   /* loop over each char in string */
    if (!isprint(*string)) {
        fputs ("error: non-printable char in input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (*string <= 'c') {   /* validate 2-digit ASCII code */
        sprintf (buf + idx, "%02d", *string); /* write ascii to buf */
        idx += 2;       /* increment index */
    }
    else {   /* handle 3-digit ASCII code */
        sprintf (buf + idx, "%03d", *string); /* write ascii to buf */
        idx += 3;       /* increment index */        
    }
    string++;       /* increment string */
}
buf[idx] = 0;       /* nul-terminate buf*/
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using input of:

```
char *string = "ABcd",
```

Results in:

```
$ ./bin/strtoasciistr
str: ABcd
buf: 656699100
longval: 656699100
```

**Taking the String to Convert as 1st Argument**

To make the program much more useful, you can read the string to convert as the first argument to the program (while also providing a default `"ABcd"` if no argument is entered) simply by using a *ternary* and `argv[1]`, e.g.

```
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *string = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "ABcd",
    ...
```

Now if you want to see, for example, if `"abcde"` is handled correctly, simply provide the string as an argument, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/strtoasciistr abcde
str: abcde
buf: 979899100101
longval: 979899100101
```

Anything else -- you are on your own. The question was answered long ago...

Comment: he asks to convert it to `long`, not to print as that format :)

Comment: That's what I thought at first -- but look closely at what he calls `long = "65666768"` where `65, 66, 67, 68` correspond to the ASCII values of `"ABCD"`. See [www.AsciiTable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I know, but he asks a `long` value that corresponds to it. at least that it is what I got from question. for me, it means something like `long val = 0; while (*string) {val = (val << sizeof(char)) + (*string); string++;  }`

Comment: Yes, I'm still a bit confused on the use of `long` -- you may be right, but I read it as he just wants to concatenate the ASCII characters for the upper case letters. The additional call to `strtol` can be made if he wants the further conversion to long.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this is not what I want. The value 65666768 should be in long variable not in char array.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if you take input from user, like scanf("%s", string) and define some max size of char array.

Comment: characters with ASCII value greater than 99 is not handled in this program

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following function will do that task ( give input string which will not cause overflow for long type)

```
long converter(char *str)
{
    char *res,*t;
    long r;

    res = calloc(3,strlen(str)+1); /* one character can expand up to 3 characters in ASCII */
    t = res;
    while(*str) {
        t += sprintf(t,"%d",*str++);
    }
    r = atol(res);
    free(res);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but this solution may cause memory leak issue

Comment: yea now I fixed it

Comment: Now, `res` is not dangling pointer (   `t` is used for traversal)

Answer (score 0):

> to store ASCII value of each character in a char array in a `long`

Much like a typical `atoi()` implementation, iterate over each character and scale the running sum by the *base* which is either 10, 100 or 1000.

```
long ASCII_to_long(const char *string) {
  long sum = 0;
  while (*string) {
    unsigned char uc = *string;
    do {
      sum *= 10;
      uc /= 10;
    } while (uc);
    sum += (unsigned char) *string;
    string++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Example use:

```
int main() {
  printf("%ld\n", ASCII_to_long("ABCD"));
  printf("%ld\n", ASCII_to_long("abcde"));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
65666768
979899100101
```

---

Additional concerns:

- No overflow protection.
- Code uses `unsigned char` to handle negative `*string`.  Yet these are unexpected as OP did say [ASCII values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) which are [0...127]

Comment: Oh yes, it's concise and hits the bullseye. The animated goal posts led to a more incremental solution in my case.